# Display a form from another class file

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, import, actionlistener

I have a running java GUI application right now in a single class file, in this application I have a button that when clicked it is used to instantiate and display a separate form from a different class file in the same project. I am confused with how I actually access this other .java file in order to instantiate and display the form from it. Hope you can help. 
Thanks, Beef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you access any class file? JFrame, JPanel, JTextField are all examples of Java source code contained in separate files. You would use:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
```

So to access your custom form your would use:

```
CustomForm form = new CustomForm();
```

As long as the class file is found on your classpath it should not be a problem.

If you are having compile or run time problems then you need to display the message so we can give further help.

Comment: thanks, but do i need an import to access the other .java file, say my other .java file is called custInfo.java that displayed a GUI form that had all the information for a customer, and then in my action event code for the button i just wanted to display the form from custInfo.java would i just do custInfo form = new custInfo(); @camickr

Comment: @Beef: you're asking this as if we can read your mind or know what your code is like without seeing it. I know we're smart and talented, but not that smart or talented, and so if you need our help, I think you're going to have give more information. I suggest that you edit your original question and provide enough information that would allow us to answer your question, but not too much information to drown us. Also, I suggest that you not create your Swing code with NetBeans code generator but rather code it by hand. You'll learn more.

Comment: Again, my comment is what have you tried and what errors are you getting??? If the class file is in the same directly as your main class file then there should not be a problem. Without code or error messages we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

I am somewhat new to Java but can't you just create another class that contains a GUI and then when you click on a JButton component you can just create an instance of that class.

```
 if (clicked == myButton) then {
        myGUIClass = new myGUIClass(); //if the GUI is in the constructors this will create 
                                       //the frame.
 }
```

Then when you are finished with the JFrame or class then you should have a dispose() method that tidies up all of your files and exits the JFrame.

Best Regards,
Doug Deines Hauf

Answer (score 0):

I think that creating a new form in Java is a bit easier than C# or Visual Basic. Basically you can just create another class and build your form in that class. Once your GUI is built then you can just create an instance of that method in another class to show the gui.

Such as:

```
if (ButtonClick == true) {
   MyGui m = new myGui(...);
   m.show
} else
  //no GUI shown here
}
```

Or you can just create an anonymous class to instantiate the GUI.

```
new myGui(...);
```

The above would create an anonymous class but I think it is better coding practice to create an actual variable of the class and then to call some method parameter that will show the GUI.